# Can JNLP API load resources during runtime?

Tags: jnlp, java-web-start, java-ws

is there a way to load JAR resources into an app during runtime? JNLP API ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/ ) is great because i have custom management of resources, but i can remove resources and if i use DownloadService.loadResource(...) it seems the resource is only downloaded, but the app will have to be started again to benefit from the new resources. Unfortunately, starting a new app and closing the currently running one is not an option for me, so is there a way to actually load these resources during runtime?

Thanks!

Comment: "..starting a new app and closing the currently running one is not an option.." Why?  `launched = basicService.showDocument(jnlpUrl)` followed by `if (launched) System.exit(0)` seems pretty trivial.

Comment: There are some problems with running multiple instances of the app, but let's assume i can get past those and would launch the JNLP again followed by System.exit(0). How will initial-heap-size and max-heap-size (both specified in the JNLP) affect this? Would it need twice the memory at startup?

Comment: "Would it need twice the memory at startup?"  Presumably.  How much does it request in Xmx?